# JSON_ENCODE tries to escape double

Tags: php, symfony, escaping, json

I am using this controller to fetch data from my database and then send them back as valid JSON data but my http response although has valid JSON, it's text/html instead of application/json so getJSON doesn't work. (unless getJSON is supposed to work anyway?)

```
  public function sendjsonAction()
  {
$encoders = array(new XmlEncoder(), new JsonEncoder());
$normalizers = array(new GetSetMethodNormalizer());
$serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);

    $message = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('AcmeStoreBundle:Message')
    ->findAll();
    $serializer = $serializer->serialize($message, 'json');
    return new Response($serializer);
}
```

**here's what I get when I visit the json url:**

[{"id":1,"iam":1,"youare":2,"lat":50.8275853,"lng":4.3809764,"msgbody":"I saw you over there what's up!"},{"id":2,"iam":1,"youare":2,"lat":50.8275853,"lng":4.3809764,"msgbody":"I saw you over there what's up!"},{"id":3,"iam":1,"youare":2,"lat":50.8275853,"lng":4.3809764,"msgbody":"I saw you over there what's up!"},{"id":4,"iam":1,"youare":2,"lat":50.8275853,"lng":4.3809764,"msgbody":"I saw you over there what's up!"},{"id":5,"iam":1,"youare":2,"lat":50.8275853,"lng":4.3809764,"msgbody":"I saw you over there what's up!"},{"id":6,"iam":1,"youare":2,"lat":50.8275853,"lng":4.3809764,"msgbody":"I saw you over there what's up!"}]

So I have another page, called "showall" which has the following Javascript:

```
$.getJSON('/app_dev.php/sendjson', function(data) {
  var items = [];

  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
  });

  $('<ul/>', {
    'class': 'my-new-list',
    html: items.join('')
  }).appendTo('body');
});
```

And the result of that JS is this html:

```
<ul class="my-new-list">
<li id="0">[object Object]</li>
<li id="1">[object Object]</li>
<li id="2">[object Object]</li>
<li id="3">[object Object]</li>
<li id="4">[object Object]</li>
<li id="5">[object Object]</li>
</ul>
```

**If I attempt to use json_encode, then things get even messier.. Here's the answer I get:**

```
"[{\"id\":1,\"iam\":1,\"youare\":2,\"lat\":50.8275853,\"lng\":4.3809764,\"msgbody\":\"I saw you over there what's up!\"},{\"id\":2,\"iam\":1,\"youare\":2,\"lat\":50.8275853,\"lng\":4.3809764,\"msgbody\":\"I saw you over there what's up!\"},{\"id\":3,\"iam\":1,\"youare\":2,\"lat\":50.8275853,\"lng\":4.3809764,\"msgbody\":\"I saw you over there what's up!\"},{\"id\":4,\"iam\":1,\"youare\":2,\"lat\":50.8275853,\"lng\":4.3809764,\"msgbody\":\"I saw you over there what's up!\"},{\"id\":5,\"iam\":1,\"youare\":2,\"lat\":50.8275853,\"lng\":4.3809764,\"msgbody\":\"I saw you over there what's up!\"},{\"id\":6,\"iam\":1,\"youare\":2,\"lat\":50.8275853,\"lng\":4.3809764,\"msgbody\":\"I saw you over there what's up!\"}]"
```

escaped double quotes... !
Should I add an option to json_encode so that it doesn't escape these double quotes?

Comment: What's wrong with the first output? When you use `getJSON`, it assumes the data is JSON and parses it accordingly. But if you just visit the URL in the browser, it doesn't do that.

Comment: I edit the post to write what happens with the first output.

Comment: I edited it. I get a list with [object] [object] strings.

Comment: `val` is an object like `{"id":1,"iam":1,"youare":2,"lat":50.8275853,"lng":4.3809764,"msgbody":"I saw you over there what's up!"}`. You need to select a particular property from it, e.g. `val.msgbody`.

Comment: Thanks, that works. So it's not really important to set the Content-Type as application/json? because now it's Content-Type:text/html; ... (add your comment as answer so I can select it please!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
```

to:

```
items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val.msgbody + '</li>');
```

You don't need to set the Content-type when using `$.getJSON` -- it assumes the output is JSON. You need it if you use more generic methods like `$.get`, `$.post`, or `$.ajax`. They all allow you to specify a `dataType: 'json'` option to tell it that the output is JSON as well, but if you leave out the option they look at the `Content-type` to decide how to parse it.

Comment: thanks, I will try to manage sending the content-type also, because I am planning to use different JS framework (Ember or backbone) and I think in this case it will matter... in case you know your way in php/symfony

Answer (score 2):

If you depend on the `Content-Type`, use [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) to set the appropriate one:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

Comment: I added $serializer->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json'); but Symfony throws an error: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: That's because `$serializer = $serializer->serialize(...)` replaces the Serializer object with a string. Don't reuse the variable like that.

Comment: Could you tell me how I can do it because I tried many different combinations but nothing worked.. I need to return a "response" which should have my content.. how do I change its headers?

Comment: I changed my code to $response = $serializer->serialize($message, 'json'); $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
return new Response($response); but I get Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\src\Acme\StoreBundle\Controller\DefaultController.php line 55